# What is the meaning of the "return" keyword inside Observable.subscribe

Tags: rxjs

Does it simply exit the function? Will it still return the unsubscription?

Comment: Where are you putting the return? Inside the handler? The return value from the handler is ignored. The call to `subscribe` itself will still return the subscription in all cases.

Comment: `return` will just exit function but not subscribe or unsubscribe anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the *.subscribe()* method always returns a subscription you can unsubscribe on. It's return value is ignored.

if you would like to work on data and continue the chain, you might want to be using *.do()* or a .*map()* instead.

Please do note that Rx chains do not do anything until you subscribe, even if you do nothing in your handler.